# Cannot add Meta Stack Overflow in my sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I cannot add Meta Stack Overflow on in the list of my sites on my phone in the Android App.

[image]

As you can see there is no option to select the meta site.

Also when I got it managed to ask a question I get the feedback that my question was deleted.

Is the app not meta ready?

I cannot open the question as well in the app.

[image]

Comment: *"I cannot add Meta Stack Overflow on in the list of my sites "*. What exactly do you mean? What happens when you try? I ask because it works fine for me on my Nexus 6. Also, if the question was deleted then that's why you can't see it on your phone. Even with 10k+ they don't show on the app. Not sure if that's intentional or not but never have for me.

Comment: I added another screenshot, there us no option for me.

Comment: If you type the full name `Meta Stack Overflow`, are you sure it doesn't show up?  I know when I searched for MSO, I had to include the full name.

Comment: Interesting. Just typing "meta" pops it up for me. You might try turning it off then back on again :P

Comment: If I scroll down the list a meter or so I find the page but as you wrote only for the keyword meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The filter was replicating what the web does, normalizing the site to "metastackoverflow meta.stackoverflow.com" but was not fulling normalizing the entered string, only getting it to "meta stack".  That space killed the search.

Now we're properly normalizing "meta stack" to "metastack".